# cytoscape.js: node labels with embedded spaces not displayed

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

If the label in the json below is changed to "hydroxylated HIF1A" (my preferred name) then the node label does not appear.

```
{
"data" : {
"id" : "64",
"SUID" : 64,
"label" : "hydroxylated-HIF1A",
"selected" : false,
"canonicalName" : "x.3091",
"copyNumber" : "0",
"name" : "x.3091",
"nodeDetail" : "",
"shared_name" : "x.3091"
}
```

session info:

- jquery-2.1.0.min.js"
- cytoscape-2.2.0.min.js"
- chrome 33.0.1750.152    (but also true with safari and firefox)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Known issue; update Cytoscape.js to latest (with fix)